# Coverage Report in Multi-Project .NET Solution

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, cobertura, coverlet

I have a .NET solution with multiple projects, structure looks like this:

```
-Solution
  -ServiceProject
  -ServiceProject.SomeClientproject
  -ServiceProject.Tests
  -ServiceProject.SomeClientProject.Test
```

`ServiceProject` is my main project, it's a service which is also using the `ServiceProject.SomeClientProject` in order to do HTTP requests to some other service. `ServiceProject.Tests` is the unit tests project for `ServiceProject`, and `ServiceProject.SomeClientProject.Test` is the unit tests project for `ServiceProject.SomeClientProject.Test`.

When I'm generating Cobertura report with Coverlet using the following command:

`dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`

2 `xml` reports are generated:

1. Coverage analysis which its source is `ServiceProject.SomeClientproject` and contains only one package for `ServiceProject.SomeClientproject`.
2. Coverage analysis which its source is `ServiceProject` and contains **two packages** - one for `ServiceProject` and another one for `ServiceProject.SomeClientproject`

Why in the second report I'm getting both packages? I want one report only for `ServiceProject.SomeClientProject` and another report only for `ServiceProject`.

Thanks!